# C++ Pi Estimating Program Not Working Correctly

Tags: c++, math

I am currently writing a program that estimates Pi values using three different formulas pictured here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjtaG.png .

This is my program so far:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  double leibniz = 0.0; // pi value calculated from Leibniz
  double counter = 0.0; // starting value
  double eulerall = 0.0; // pi value calculated from Euler (all integers)
  double eulerodd = 0.0; // value calculated from Euler (odds)

  int terms;
  bool negatives = false;

  cin >> terms;
  cout << fixed << setprecision(12); // set digits after decimal to 12                   \

  while(terms > counter){
    leibniz = 4*(pow(-1, counter)) / (2*counter+1) + leibniz;
    counter++;
    eulerall = sqrt(6/pow(counter+1,2)) + eulerall;
    counter++;
    eulerodd = (sqrt(32)*pow(-1, counter)) / (2*counter + 1) + eulerodd;
    counter++;

    cout << terms << " " << leibniz << " " << eulerall << " " << eulerodd <<endl;
  }

  if (terms < 0){
    if(!negatives)
    negatives=true;
    cout << "There were " << negatives << " negative values read" << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The sample input file that I am using is:
1
6
-5
100
-1000000
0

And the sample output for this input file is:

```
1 4.000000000000 2.449489742783 3.174802103936
6 2.976046176046 2.991376494748 3.141291949057
100 3.131592903559 3.132076531809 3.141592586052
```

When I run my program all I get as an output is:

```
1 4.000000000000 1.224744871392 1.131370849898.
```

So as you can see my first problem is that the second and third of my equations are wrong and I can't figure out why. My second problem is that the program only reads the first input value and stops there. I was hoping you guys could help me figure this out. Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You have three problems:

**First,** you do not implement the Euler formulae correctly.

π<sup>2</sup>/6 = 1/1<sup>2</sup> + 1/2<sup>2</sup> + 1/3<sup>2</sup> + ...

```
eulerall = sqrt(6/pow(counter+1,2)) + eulerall;
```

The square root of the sum is *not* the sum of the square roots.

π<sup>3</sup>/32 = 1/1<sup>3</sup> + 1/3<sup>3</sup> + 1/5<sup>3</sup> + ...

```
eulerodd = (sqrt(32)*pow(-1, counter)) / (2*counter + 1) + eulerodd;
```

This is just... wrong.

**Second,** you increment `counter` three times in the loop, instead of once:

```
while(terms > counter){
...
counter++;
...
counter++;
...
counter++;
...
}
```

**Third, and most fundamental,** you didn't follow the basic rule of software development: start small and simple, add complexity as little at a time, test at every step, and *never add to code that doesn't work.*

Comment: Hello, Beta. Sorry for the late reply, I've been in a few lectures. I took out the extra counter++ and fixed the euler all equation. The third one is still giving me problems, but I should be able to figure it out. However, I have a problem in the way that my program accepts the inputs. It will only take the first value in the file and stop there. Also instead of outputting the estimation for PI for the given term only, it will list all estimations from 1 to the given term. For example, if the term was 6, it will list all estimations from 1-6, but I just want the estimation for 6.

Comment: # TERMS       LEIBINZ     EULER-ALL     EULER-ODD
             6 4.000000000000 2.449489742783 1.000000000000
       # TERMS       LEIBINZ     EULER-ALL     EULER-ODD
             6 2.666666666667 2.738612787526 1.000000000000
       # TERMS       LEIBINZ     EULER-ALL     EULER-ODD
             6 3.466666666667 2.857738033247 1.000000000000
       # TERMS       LEIBINZ     EULER-ALL     EULER-ODD
             6 2.895238095238 2.922612986125 1.000000000000

Comment: # TERMS       LEIBINZ     EULER-ALL     EULER-ODD
             6 3.339682539683 2.963387701039 1.000000000000
       # TERMS       LEIBINZ     EULER-ALL     EULER-ODD
             6 2.976046176046 2.991376494748 1.000000000000
Here's an example of what I was talking about. Sorry for all the questions, but I've been stuck on this for awhile.

Comment: @user3409117: Put the output command *after* the loop, not *in* it, and it will give you what you want. As for file I/O, I can't diagnose the problem without seeing the code, but if you do a Google search for "C++ file input" you'll see plenty of examples.

Answer (score 2):

> my first problem is that the second and third of my equations are
>   wrong and I can't figure out why

Use counter++ just once. Apart from this Leibniz looks fine.
Eulerall is not correct, you should sum all factors and then **do sqrt and multiplication at the end**:

```
eulerall = 1/pow(counter+1,2) + eulerall;
// do sqrt and multiplication at the end to get Pi
```

The similar thing with eulerodd: you should sum all factors and then **do sqrt and multiplication at the end**.

> My second problem is that the program only reads the first input value
>   and stops there.

In fact this is your first problem. This is because you are incrementing `counter` multiple times:

```
while(terms > counter){
leibniz = 4*(pow(-1, counter)) / (2*counter+1) + leibniz;
counter++;  // <<  increment
^^^^^^^^^^
eulerall = sqrt(6/pow(counter+1,2)) + eulerall;
counter++;  // <<  increment
^^^^^^^^^^
eulerodd = (sqrt(32)*pow(-1, counter)) / (2*counter + 1) + eulerodd;
counter++;  // <<  increment
^^^^^^^^^^
cout << terms << " " << leibniz << " " << eulerall << " " << eulerodd <<endl;
}
```

You should increment `counter` just once.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the same `counter` and incrementing it after each calculation. So each technique is only accounting for every third term. You should increment `counter` only once, at the end of the loop.

Also note that it is generally bad form to use a floating-point value as a loop counter. It only takes on integer values in your program, so you can just make it an `int`. Nothing else needs to change; the math will run the same because the `int` will promote to a `double` when you combine the two in math operations.

Answer (score -1):

```
    #include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
char* main()
{
    while(1)
    {
        int Precision;
        float answer = 0;
        cout<<"Enter your desired precision to find pi number : ";
        cin>>Precision;
        for(int i = 1;i <= Precision;++i)
        {
            int sign = (pow((-1),static_cast<float>(i + 1)));
            answer += sign * 4 * ( 1 / float( 2 * i - 1));
        }
            cout<<"Your answer is equal to : "<<answer<<endl;
        _getch();
        _flushall();
        system("cls");
    }
    return "That is f...";
}
```

Comment: this code first your desired precision then calculate the pi number. here precision means that how many times we do sum the numbers to find the pi number.